# How to check if a key is present in json using ijson module python?

Tags: python

I have a json file and I'm using ijson for the same but for different files the top-level key is different. Is there any way I can find if the key is present or not

```
    f = open(filename)
    objects = ijson.items(f, "BulkData.item") # If BulkData is a key or not
```

Comment: You can do that with the ijson low-level interfaces: https://pypi.org/project/ijson/#lower-level-interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say that you have JSON like:

```json
{
 "a": {
   "b": "c"
  }
}
```

And your code is:

```py
key = "a.b"

with open("example.json") as f:
  objects = ijson.items(f, key)
  objects_list = list(objects)
  if len(objects_list) == 0:
    result_value = None
  else:
    result_value = objects_list[0]

if result_value is not None:
  print(result_value)
else:
  print(f"here is no {key} key")
```

if you set `a.b` key `c` will be printed

in other case `here is no key` will be printed